# Can WaitHandle.WaitOne with ExitContext flag be used without ContextBoundObject class?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

MSDN documentation suggests that there may be other ways of using ExitContext flag. See [WaitHandle.WaitOne()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx) What other ways are there to enter a non-default context outside of using a ContextBoundObject inherited class?  (I can't use ContextBoundObject in my application)

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in this sentence.

> Even if you are currently executing a
>   method on a class that does not derive
>   from ContextBoundObject, like String,
>   you can be in a nondefault context if
>   a ContextBoundObject is on your stack
>   in the current application domain.

So basically you could call `WaitOne` from within a class that does not subclass `ContextBoundObject` nor would you have any preconceived notion that a `ContextBoundObject` was in any way involved with your code and yet the thread in question could be in a nondefault context because somewhere way up in the call stack an instance method of a `ContextBoundObject` class could be running unbeknown to you.

Outside of that lone exception there are no other ways of entering into a nondefault synchronization context.

There is a pretty good article on threading with additional information related to synchronization contexts which can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization_Contexts).

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  Although, apparently you can use ContextAttribute as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.contextattribute.aspx.  I still haven't been able to use it or see an example of how it's used without ContextBoundObject.

Comment: I'll have to be honest here. I am not familiar with `ContextAttribute` nor how it would be used.

Comment: That's makes two of us ;) Perhaps someone will shed more light on ContextAttribute.  I think I have to post a new question regarding what scenarios constitute a non-default context.